# Proving differentiability from left- and right-handed derivative

Tags: real-analysis

If we know the left- and right-handed derivative of $f$ are equal at a point $x_o$, do we need to know $f$ is continuous at $x_o$ to show $f$ is differentiable at $x_o$? Although continuity of course is necessary for differentiability, I think intuitively that the left- and right-handed derivative can only be equal at $x_o$ if $f$ is continuous at $x_o$ so mentioning that $f$ is continuous at $x_o$ is not necessary for the proof.

Comment: The very fact that left hand derivative (LHD) and RHD are equal at a point $x_0$ implies existence of the derivative at that point, which of course means that the function is continuous at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Let me bring example: consider simple $f(x)=x$, which is infinitely differentiable in any point of $\mathbb{R}$ and then redefine it in one unique point only. It lost continuity at this point and so for it is impossible to have derivative. But limits left and right as for $f$ so for $f^{'}$ holds from left and right of chosen point. So we have $f^{'}(x_0 \pm)=\lim_{x \to x_0 \pm}f^{'}(x)$ $(1)$ holds.

But if under left and right derivative we understand $\lim\limits_{h \to 0 \pm}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ $(2)$ then existence and equality to one value these limits implies existence of $\lim\limits_{h \to 0 }\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ and implies, obviously, continuity.

Comment: Doesn't your answer confuse the left- and right-handed limit of the derivative for the left- and right-handed derivative? Those are different objects. I am asking about the latter, not the former.

Comment: @maththrowaway2468. I brought example for $f^{'}(x_0 \pm)=\lim_{x \to x_0 \pm}f^{'}(x)$, they holds same. But to avoid ambiguity I added second variant to answer also.

Comment: I don't mean any offense, but your English is somewhat difficult to understand, but I believe what you've written implies that the answer to my question is "Yes". Is that correct?

Comment: @maththrowaway2468. When/if you mean in your question $(2)$ formula from my answer, not $(1)$, then answer is definitely yes and I wrote it above. Your estimating of my poor English means that you are native speaker, yes? Sorry for it.